# ORA-00955 error while implementing Hangfire.FluentNHibernateStorage

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate, hangfire

Hi my oracle version is:

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

I am using Hangfire.FluentNHibernateStorage v1.2.1020 version.

In owin startup here what I am doing in Configuration method:

```
    var options = new FluentNHibernateStorageOptions
        {
            TransactionIsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable,
            QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
            JobExpirationCheckInterval = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
            CountersAggregateInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            UpdateSchema = true,
            
            DashboardJobListLimit = 50000,
            InvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            TransactionTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3),
            DefaultSchema = "hangfire_test", 
            TablePrefix = "Hangfire_"
        };

        var conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var storage = FluentNHibernateStorageFactory.For(ProviderTypeEnum.OracleClient10, conStr, options);

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseStorage(storage);
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
```

In this line:

```
 var storage = FluentNHibernateStorageFactory.For(ProviderTypeEnum.OracleClient10, conStr, options);
```

the code throws error saying:

```
    [OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-00955: 
]
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.CheckError(OciErrorHandle errorHandle, Int32 rc) +337363
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.Execute(OciStatementHandle statementHandle, CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor, ArrayList& resultParameterOrdinals) +1103
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQueryInternal(Boolean needRowid, OciRowidDescriptor& rowidDescriptor) +547
   System.Data.OracleClient.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +115
   NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.Execute(Action`1 scriptAction, Boolean doUpdate) +726

[SchemaException: Schema update failed with 2 exceptions.  See Exceptions property]
   Snork.FluentNHibernateTools.<>c__DisplayClass7_3.<GetSessionFactoryInfo>b__1(Configuration cfg) in C:\Users\xrjef\source\repos\Snork.FluentNHibernateTools\src\Snork.FluentNHibernateTools\SessionFactoryBuilder.cs:115
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() in /_/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/FluentConfiguration.cs:257

[FluentConfigurationException: An invalid or incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more detail.

]
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildConfiguration() in /_/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/FluentConfiguration.cs:262
   FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfiguration.BuildSessionFactory() in /_/src/FluentNHibernate/Cfg/FluentConfiguration.cs:230

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with what you are doing, but - ORA-00955 means "name is already used by an existing object".

For example: there's a table named TEST in my schema. If I try to create a procedure whose name is TEST, Oracle will complain that I can't do that because object with such a name already exists. To illustrate it:

```
SQL> create table test (id number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure test as
  2  begin
  3    null;
  4  end;
  5  /
create or replace procedure test as
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object


SQL>
```

So: check what you are doing and either drop object that already uses that name (if you don't need it), or rename the object you're trying to create.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but the Hangfire.FluentNHibernateStorage library is the one that creates the tables.

Comment: it seems like the lib is trying to create the same table again.

Comment: If that's the case, well, it won't work. Drop it (if possible) before running your code, or handle the exception (if you can), or rename the table.